# GAS - Wait until user enters data before function continues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script, datepicker

I'm just starting with GAS so I would appreciate any insight and apologize if this is an obvious question. I am trying to implement a date picker so that a user can choose some dates instead of typing them out. I do this using the code from this question:

[Returning a value using Date picker in HTMLService / Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841089/returning-a-value-using-date-picker-in-htmlservice-google-apps-script)

This works great, but my issue is that the rest of my code continues to run before the user can input dates. The function to call the html is:

```
function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dateDialog')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Please provide a Date Range');
  Logger.log("HTML return = %s", html.getContent());     
  return html.getContent();
}
```

And I call this from my main script file below. The picker shows up but then the rest of my code continues to execute. In this case, I have a msgBox that pops up and closes the datepicker.

```
function runthis(){
  var a = showDialog();
  Logger.log(a);

  //rest of code would go here
  Browser.msgBox('hello world');
}
```

I guess I could loop some timeout or pause until the html has returned values but this seems unnecessary. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: The `showModalDialog` does not block the code execution (doing that will cause the browser UI to freeze. You will need to pass a callback to your modal dialog and execute that when dismissing the dialog to proceed executing your code. I am not experienced with google app script to post a answer describing as to set up the callback, sorry.

Comment: Thanks Prusse, this set me on the right path to figure out the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the correct way to go about this. Basically I needed to reorder how I was calling different functions and where I was beginning my code. Maybe this question should be deleted, or maybe this will be useful, I don't know.

I was calling `showDialog()` from my entry point: `runthis()` and so the subsequent code in `runthis()` was executing, undesirably.

Instead, I changed the entry point to my scripts to be `showDialog()` and then from there I could pass the user entered data to `runthis()`

Really silly mistake, but hopefully this is helpful to someone else who is new to using `HtmlService`

EDIT:
I call the datepicker first:

```
function showDialog(){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('DateDialog')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Pick a date')
}
```

Which then calls the modal dialog in the separate html file:

```
<div class="demo" >
<style type="text/css"> .demo { margin: 30px ; color : #AAA ; font-family : arial sans-serif ;font-size : 10pt } 
                        p { color : red ; font-size : 11pt } 
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet"     href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-    ui.css">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<p>Please select a date below :</p>

<p> Start Date : <input type="text" name="StartDate" id="startdatepicker" />     </p>
<p> End Date :   <input type="text" name="EndDate" id="enddatepicker" />  </p>
<script>
$( "#startdatepicker" ).datepicker({
  showWeek: true,
  firstDay: 0,
 });
</script>
<script>
$( "#enddatepicker" ).datepicker({
  showWeek: true,
  firstDay: 0,
 });
</script>
<input type="button" value="Create" onclick="submitDates()" />
<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />


<script>
// Pass input dates to server-side submitDates()
function submitDates() {
  var startDate = $("#startdatepicker").val();
  var endDate = $("#enddatepicker").val();

  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(
       // Dates delivered, close dialog
       function() {
         google.script.host.close();
       })
       // Display failure messages
     .withFailureHandler(
       function() {
         var div = $('<div id="error" class="error">' + msg + '</div>');
         $(element).after($("#demo"));
       })
     .submitDates(startDate,endDate);
}

</script>
</div>
```

Which passes the dates to a server-side function which then sends data to several other functions, in this case just one, `Timesheet`(instead of `runthis()`)

```
function submitDates(startDate,endDate) {
     Timesheet(startDate,endDate);
}
```

Probably lots to clean up and simplify but haven't had the time to do that yet, just glad it is working!