# How to get value of datepicker in Google Scripts Apps

Tags: google-apps-script, datepicker

I am trying to get the value of the date which the user selects using datepicker. Once they select the date I want to be able to use the string for later. I have followed the extremely helpful answer found here: [Returning a value using Date picker in HTMLService / Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841089/returning-a-value-using-date-picker-in-htmlservice-google-apps-script)

I know I need to get it to the back end but am struggling to do so and I am sure there is a dumb mistake which I am missing because I am still learning. Here is the code, any help is welcoming.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">
   <form id='findDate'>

Date:<input type="button" id = "date" onclick = "submitDates()" />

</form>

<script>
    $("#date").datepicker({
      showWeek: true,
      firstDay: 0,
      });
</script>

    <script>
function submitDates() {
  var dateDes = $("#date").val();
  google.script.run.submitDates(dataDes);
}
</script>
```

The part I am most confused about is setting the value of the button and what to do with the onclick as I am sure I am not getting the value assigned. This is where it is supposed to get sent in the end.

```
function submitDates(dateDes) {

  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(dateDes));
  //goal is to set the datedes string to setDescription using the File Class
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried checking the View --> Logs to validate if there is any input passed to your Google Apps Script? Or any error logs triggered in the developer's console?