# How to get user input in string-form on a google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am making a program that requires you to ask the user for an input of a date (which I will take in through them just inputting a date through MMDDYYY form). I'm just confused on how to implement this, as my script incorporates the use of Google Calendar.

In this site: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response

They have a class called PromptResponse, which is instantiated through doing `DocumentApp.getUI()` or `SpreadsheetApp.getUI();`

Can I do this by doing `CalendarApp.getUI()`? Or do I need another way?

And if I can do it that way, for the method getResponseText(), when I call it, does it ask the user then and there (looking at the way they used it in the link)? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call [one of the `ui.prompt()` methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui), it opens the dialog and interacts with the user. When the user dismisses the dialog, `ui.prompt()` returns the `PromptResponse` object which contains all the results of that interaction.

You can then query the `PromptResponse` object (i.e. call `response.getResponseText()` and `response.getSelectedButton()`) to find out what text the user entered and what button the user clicked in the dialog.

The [CalendarApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app) object does *not* have a `getUI()` method nor a "Tools > Script editor" menu command.

Instead, attach an Apps Script UI to a [Google Sheet, Doc, or Form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) or create a [standalone script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) and run it from there. The script can prompt the user for input and then call on the Calendar API to do something like add a Calendar event.

Also, consider looking for [a date-picker library](https://www.google.com/search?q=google%20apps%20script%20date%20picker).

**Example in a Google Sheets script**

```
/** Demonstrates a simple way to prompt the user for a date. */
function promptForDate() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Create a Calendar Event', 'Enter a date in MMDDYYYY form', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    Logger.log('TODO: Create a Calendar Event for date %s', response.getResponseText());
    ui.alert('TODO: Create a Calendar Event for date ' + response.getResponseText());
  } else if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
   Logger.log('The user canceled the dialog.');
  } else {
   Logger.log('The user closed the dialog.');
  }
}

/** Adds a menu to the Google Sheet. */
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Prompt For Date', 'promptForDate')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Yeah I'm currently making a standalone script in trying to accomplish my goal. And question (just I'm so new to Google Scripts), how would the script prompt the user for input in this case? And thank you so much for the answer, this was incredibly helpful!!!

Comment: @Anthony I added a Sheets script example. Hope it helps!

Comment: It seems that your link to the date picker library leads to UiApp service examples, this is now deprecated. A better choice would probably be the JQUERY UI library in an HTML served UI.

Comment: @Sergeinsas the first Google search result is a deprecated API. Do examine more of those search results.

Comment: Not only the first one... The 5 top results are about UiApp. If you take the 6th it is JQUERY, presently (probably) the best approach. Or have I misunderstood something ?

Comment: Indeed. Search results vary, but at #5 I see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22123371/date-picker-in-htmlservice-google-apps-script

Comment: @Jerry101 Thank you very much for this, you have been so helpful! Just one question that's been bugging me.

In the "var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();" line, what exactly does this do? Does it create a new Spreadsheet or what? Eventually I want to actually move all the data I collect to a spreadsheet so thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: Also a couple more questions: In the onOpen() method, when you do the .addItem(), it calls the promptForDate method but then what does that do? The promptForDate method doesn't return anything (it does in my version), and then how would i access that item from the menu? Thanks @Jerry101

Comment: @anthony the .getUi() method doesn't create a spreadsheet. It just gets an object that handles user interaction (UI). I think an introduction to object-oriented programming would be helpful. The above example promptForDate() just puts the date string that the user entered into the log and shows it in an alert. This is just to demo the input code. Your script would replace that part. Instead parse the input string as a date and then do something useful with it, e.g. pass it to a Calendar method that creates a new event.

Comment: @Jerry101 Thank you, that answered a lot of questions. You've been so helpful today, you're a real lifesaver! Kind of a semi-unrelated question, but is there any chance you would know how to like convert a Google Spreadsheet to a PDF? I'm thinking of implementing such a thing in my code. I can't really find stuff on how to do it without going for something massively complicated. Otherwise, with the data I grab from the calendar, I'll just add a file to Drive. Thanks!!1

Comment: That's a new question, but briefly, one can manually print to PDF and maybe export as PDF, but the script API doesn't seem to do that.