# GAS: How to re-size datepicker drop-down from DateBox

Tags: google-apps-script

I know this is deprecated but I'd still like to know how I can customize the datepicker calendar that pops up when I click on my DateBox.

```
var dateBox1 = app.createDateBox().setId('date1').setName('showDates')
grid.setWidget(12, 2, dateBox1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the possible resizing methods of [DatePicker](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/date-picker) and the size of the pop-up calendar still remained the same.

- [setPixelSize](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/date-picker#setpixelsizewidth-height)
- [setSize](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/date-picker#setsizewidth-height)
- [setHeight](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/date-picker#setheightheight)
- [setWidth](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/date-picker#setwidthwidth)

I think you have a better chance of configuring this using the new [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/).

[SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22123371/date-picker-in-htmlservice-google-apps-script) for additonal reference.

Comment: I think you're right.. I was really hoping I wouldn't have to redo my entire script to HTML (for a web app), but I'm thinking there's just no other way - that I know of at least.

Comment: Well, this certainly isn't the answer I am looking for.. But I do appreciate the response.
(Also, I have less than 15 rep, so my up-vote will not be displayed.)